# Access Object value in a string and compare

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var siteList = {};
var siteInfo = [];
var part_str = '[{"part":"00000PD","partSupplier":"DELL"}]';
var part =  part_str.substring(1,part_str.length-1);

eval('var partobj='+part );
console.log(partobj.part);
console.log(partobj.partSupplier);
```

The above code works fine.
But I have to find out if the part number matches the following part; if not, the `partSupplier` will be added to the following json; else not.

```js
if (partobj.part.includes("00000PD")){
  var partSupp= partobj.partSupplier;
} else {
  partSupp= "HP";
}

siteInfo = {
  "Parts_Num": part,
  "partSupplier": partSupp
}
siteList.siteInfo.push(siteInfo);
```

I tried the following, but the `partSupplier` value is empty:

```
if (partobj.part.includes("00000PD")){
  var  partSupp = [partobj.partSupplier];
  console.log('partSupp' || partSupp);
} else {
  partSupp = "HP";
}
```

The result from the console:

```
partSupp
It does not return any value.
```

I am using console.log to test the output before plugging the code.

Comment: If you want to compare `part`, why are you trying to compare `partnumber` (which doesn't even exist) and `partSupplier`?

Comment: Consider using `JSON.parse()` over `eval()`, especially if the `part_str` could contain user values.

Comment: What is `console.log('partSupp' || partSupp);` supposed to do? String `'partSupp'` is always truthy. It always just prints "partSupp". Even if you swap them around, `partSupp` will also be always truthy. The if statement isn't even syntactically correct, as there a misplaced `}`.

Comment: And do you know what `includes` does? Are you sure you want that and not just equality (`==`)?

Comment: Also [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45015)

Comment: [Now the problem isn't reproducible.](https://jsfiddle.net/16s7f0qz/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse` to get an array from the string, then use `Array#find` to get the object with a matching `part`.

```js
const part_str = '[{"part":"00000PD","partSupplier":"DELL"}]';
const arr = JSON.parse(part_str);
const match = arr.find(o => o.part.includes("00000PD"));
if (match) {
  console.log(match.partSupplier);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes a modification to your original questions.

The highlight is at like, 5, where the `part_str` is converted to JSON array, then like 7 picked the first item - I assume this is what you want to do.

Then check if the `partObj.part` contains the particular string to get the `partSupplier`, else return `"HP"`

Finally use the information to create a `siteInfo` object before pushing it to the `siteList` object

```js
var siteList = {
  siteInfo []
};
var part_str = '[{"part":"00000PD","partSupplier":"DELL"}]';

const partArr = JSON.parse(part_str)

var partObj = partArr[0]
var partSubpp = partObj?.part?.includes("00000PD") ? partObj.partSupplier : "HP"

siteInfo = {
  "Parts_Num": part,
  "partSupplier": partSupp
}
siteList.siteInfo.push(siteInfo);
```